# how to get numbers from string in LUA?

Tags: lua

I have string "0,0,0,-58.43083113,,"

and how could I get all the 4 numbers as double with LUA? Thanks!

I have tried with string.match(). But it didn't work.

Comment: you should add what you have tried. not just name a function. post your code

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - please take the [tour] - also read our [ask] page for tips on how to improve this question.  For starters, *"It didn't work"* does not describe the issue.  Show us what you tried and what errors or issues you are getting.

Comment: Would you accept "I tried with string.match() and it worked for me" as the answer? Probably not, so similarly you should provide some details on what you did and the result you received (and why you think it's an invalid one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
local text = "0,0,0,-58.43083113,,"

local numbers = {}
text:gsub("[^,]+", function (str) table.insert(numbers, tonumber(str)+.0) end)
print(table.concat(numbers, ", "))
```

or

```
for str in text:gmatch("[^,]+") do
  table.insert(numbers, tonumber(str) + .0)
end
```

Of course this assumes that you only have number representations and commas in your string.

Comment: What does `tonumber(str)+.0` do? Why `+.0`?

Comment: @lhf - It convert integer to a double. http://www.differencebetween.info/difference-between-integer-and-double

Comment: @lhf it's not necessary but the OP requested "doubles". just to avoid complaints about receiving integers. :)

Comment: Perhaps you could add this explanation to your answer.